# Energy of a discrete-time decaying exponential

Tags: discrete-signals

Given the signal

$$x[n]=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^nu[n]$$

I want to find its energy

$$E_\infty = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}|x[n]|^2$$

So how can I compute $E_\infty$? Could anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to DSP SE. This looks like a homework to me. What did you do so far? Any calculations? Have tried to plot the signal? Is the energy finite or not? How about power? I am sure that you know equation: $P=\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}{2N+1}\sum_{n=-N}^{N}|x(n)|^2$.

Comment: Try answering these questions. 1) What does the term $0.5^{2n}$ tend to as $n$ tends to infinity? 2) Is the sum finite or infinite? 3) Does that sum look similar to something you've solved before, maybe from calculus class (except with an integral instead of a sum)?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $u[n]$ denotes the unit step function, equal to $1$ when $n\ge 0$ and $0$ elsewhere, then:
$$ \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x[n]|^2 = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{2n} = \sum_{0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^{n} = \frac{1-0}{1-\frac{1}{4}} = \frac{4}{3}\,.$$